# bootstrap Carousel fade in and out display issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please bare with my poor drawing.

As you can see from the image below. I am using a bootstrap Carousel control which is reference from

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Within the control I am setting the carousel as

```
<div class="carousel carousel-fade slide home-slider....>
....
</div>
```

which would make it have the effect of fade-in and fade-out on sliding.

And I am making the "Front element" (in red) sits on the top of the carousel by making its `"style='margin-top:-40px'"`

My issue here is that every time the sliding animation triggered, the front element is having this fade-in/out effect as well which is not desirable.

How can I make the front element as non-flashing while keeping the background carousel has the effect. Is that possible?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please post your html and css here or in jsfiddle.

Comment: Finally what I did was just instead of using "carousel-fade" I was using "carousel-slide", which is a walk around fro me..

Answer (score 0):

create a custom-container div with `position:relative` and put the Carousel inside the container, then make your Front element as `position: absolute` and put it in the container Out of the Carousel. so the place of your Front element is after last Carousel closed tag and before the container closed tag.
structure:

```
<div clas="container" style="position:relative">
[Carousel]
<fronElement style="position: absolute;bottom:40px" ></frontElement>
</div>
```